# purrr -- looping all variables within a specific pattern to run correlational analyses

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, correlation, purrr

Let's say I have this kind of dataset:

```
ds <- data.frame(question1 = sample(1:10),
                 question2 = sample(1:10),
                 question3 = sample(1:10),

                 question1_a = sample(1:10),
                 question2_a = sample(1:10),
                 question3_a = sample(1:10))
```

And I want to check the intraclass correlation of question1 and question1_a; question2 and question2_a; question3 and question3_a. [That's the pattern = number + number_a].

I'm going this way:

```
library(psych)
library(tidyverse)

ICC(cbind(ds$question1, ds$question1_a))
ICC(cbind(ds$question2, ds$question2_a))
```

But I'm pretty sure it's possible to perform all ICC analyses within tidyverse functions (purrr / map), but I'm facing a hard time to implement this solution.

Thanks for any help.

Entire code:

```
library(psych)
library(tidyverse)
ds <- data.frame(question1 = sample(1:10),
                 question2 = sample(1:10),
                 question3 = sample(1:10),

                 question1_a = sample(1:10),
                 question2_a = sample(1:10),
                 question3_a = sample(1:10))

ICC(cbind(ds$question1, ds$question1_a))
ICC(cbind(ds$question2, ds$question2_a))
```

Comment: Try something like this: `Map(function(x, y) psych::ICC(cbind(x,y)), df1, df2)`. `df1` and `df2` are subset with `select` and regex matches. I have some issues with purrr, don't know if it's a bug or something local but you can stay tidyverse core with purrr's looping functions `map*`, etc

Comment: Not working this way: ds %>% 
  Map(function(x, y) psych::ICC(cbind(x,y)), 
      select(ds,contains("question")), select(ds,contains("_")))
Would you suggest any change? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve the above as follows:

```
 set.seed(233)  
  library(dplyr)
  # There might be a better way rather than selecting twice.
  # assumes an ordered dataframe
    ds %>% 
      select(matches(".*\\d$")) -> df1
    ds %>% 
      select(contains("_")) -> df2 


Map(function(x, y) psych::ICC(cbind(x,y)), df1, df2)
```

Or using just `base`. I do note that this might be computationally expensive because of repeated subsets and a further call to `cbind`.

```
Map(function(x, y) psych::ICC(cbind(x,y)), ds[grep(".*\\d$",names(ds))], 
    ds[grep("_",names(ds))])
```

Sample output:

```
$question1
Call: psych::ICC(x = cbind(x, y))

Intraclass correlation coefficients 
                         type  ICC   F df1 df2    p lower bound upper bound
Single_raters_absolute   ICC1 0.24 1.6   9  10 0.23       -0.40        0.73
Single_random_raters     ICC2 0.24 1.6   9   9 0.24       -0.41        0.73
Single_fixed_raters      ICC3 0.24 1.6   9   9 0.24       -0.42        0.73
Average_raters_absolute ICC1k 0.38 1.6   9  10 0.23       -1.33        0.84
Average_random_raters   ICC2k 0.38 1.6   9   9 0.24       -1.38        0.85
Average_fixed_raters    ICC3k 0.38 1.6   9   9 0.24       -1.48        0.85

 Number of subjects = 10     Number of Judges =  2
$question2
Call: psych::ICC(x = cbind(x, y))
```

Data(seed is set to 233):

```
ds <- structure(list(question1 = c(6L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 
7L, 1L), question2 = c(7L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 4L
), question3 = c(3L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 10L, 4L), question1_a = c(4L, 
6L, 2L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 3L), question2_a = c(9L, 1L, 
10L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 6L), question3_a = c(9L, 4L, 3L, 
6L, 1L, 5L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Thanks much! For my personal understanding. What does matches(".*\\d$")) performs ?

Comment: It is a RegEx wildcard that matches anything(`.*`) that ends in a digit(`\\d$`).

Comment: Thanks!  Now I've got it!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `purrr` and not having to create intermediate dataframes

```
library(psych)
library(tidyverse)

ds <- data.frame(question1 = sample(1:10),
                 question2 = sample(1:10),
                 question3 = sample(1:10),

                 question1_a = sample(1:10),
                 question2_a = sample(1:10),
                 question3_a = sample(1:10))

map2(ds %>% select(matches(".*\\d$")), ds %>% select(matches(".*_a$")), 
     function (x, y) ICC(cbind(x, y)))
```

The two regex expressions match columns ending with a digit and columns ending with "_a". It produces

```
$question1
Call: ICC(x = cbind(x, y))

Intraclass correlation coefficients 
                         type  ICC   F df1 df2     p lower bound upper bound
Single_raters_absolute   ICC1 0.52 3.2   9  10 0.044      -0.090        0.85
Single_random_raters     ICC2 0.52 3.2   9   9 0.051      -0.094        0.85
Single_fixed_raters      ICC3 0.52 3.2   9   9 0.051      -0.122        0.85
Average_raters_absolute ICC1k 0.68 3.2   9  10 0.044      -0.199        0.92
Average_random_raters   ICC2k 0.68 3.2   9   9 0.051      -0.206        0.92
Average_fixed_raters    ICC3k 0.68 3.2   9   9 0.051      -0.277        0.92

 Number of subjects = 10     Number of Judges =  2
$question2
Call: ICC(x = cbind(x, y))

Intraclass correlation coefficients 
                         type  ICC   F df1 df2    p lower bound upper bound
Single_raters_absolute   ICC1 0.37 2.2   9  10 0.12       -0.27        0.79
Single_random_raters     ICC2 0.37 2.2   9   9 0.13       -0.28        0.79
Single_fixed_raters      ICC3 0.37 2.2   9   9 0.13       -0.30        0.79
Average_raters_absolute ICC1k 0.54 2.2   9  10 0.12       -0.75        0.88
Average_random_raters   ICC2k 0.54 2.2   9   9 0.13       -0.77        0.88
Average_fixed_raters    ICC3k 0.54 2.2   9   9 0.13       -0.86        0.89

 Number of subjects = 10     Number of Judges =  2
$question3
Call: ICC(x = cbind(x, y))

Intraclass correlation coefficients 
                         type  ICC   F df1 df2     p lower bound upper bound
Single_raters_absolute   ICC1 0.45 2.6   9  10 0.074       -0.18        0.82
Single_random_raters     ICC2 0.45 2.6   9   9 0.083       -0.18        0.83
Single_fixed_raters      ICC3 0.45 2.6   9   9 0.083       -0.21        0.83
Average_raters_absolute ICC1k 0.62 2.6   9  10 0.074       -0.44        0.90
Average_random_raters   ICC2k 0.62 2.6   9   9 0.083       -0.45        0.90
Average_fixed_raters    ICC3k 0.62 2.6   9   9 0.083       -0.53        0.91

 Number of subjects = 10     Number of Judges =  2
```

Comment: I think it's the same thing. Putting the select calls in `map2` does not in my naive opinion reduce computational time. There is probably a better way that I am(we are) missing.

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks!